# When is $3^n + n$ a power of 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For what $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $3^n + n$ a power of $2$?

Comment: $n$ cannot be even...

Comment: $n$ also cannot be a power of three, but I need to know precisely which $n$.

Comment: Hint: what is $3^n \pmod 2$?  Also, what does "this question has to be longer and longer still" mean?

Comment: @Patrick, "this question has to be longer and longer still" means that the question's brevity did not meet site quality standards, and it required more characters to be able to post. Also, my first attempt at adding extra characters was insufficient.

Comment: @user125053 I guess you are looking for ALL the values of $n$ that work? Assuming that there are finite of them?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @imranfat That's the usual meaning of "when is..."

Comment: I know there are a finite number of them -- through magic -- but I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Yeah yeah, ok. I took my answer off. It couldn't be that simple :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete solution, but shows that any nontrival solutions must be mindbogglingly big if it exists at all.

We have the trivial solutions $3^0+0=2^0$ and $3^1+1=2^2$.
Assume $3^n+n=2^m$ with $n\ge 2$. Then clearly $m>n$.
We find $1+n\equiv 0\pmod 2$, hene $n$ is odd. Then $3^n\equiv 3\pmod 8$ and hence $n\equiv 5\pmod 8$, esp. $m\ge 6$.
From $3^8\equiv 1\pmod{32}$ we have $3^n\equiv 19\pmod{32}$, hence $n\equiv 13\pmod {32}$. A pattern emerges.

**Lemma:** For $k\in\mathbb N$ we have $3^{2^k}\equiv 1\pmod {2^{k+2}}$

*Proof:* This is true for $k=1$ and from
$$3^{2^{k+1}}-1=(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^k}+1) $$
the claim follows by indcution because $3^{2^k}+1$ is even. $_\square$

**Propositio:** Assume for some $1\le k< a<2^k$ we have that for all nontrivial solutions of $3^n+n=2^m$ we have $n\equiv a\pmod{2^k}$.
Then  for all nontrivial solutions of $3^n+n=2^m$ we have $n\equiv -3^a\pmod{2^{k+2}}$.

*Proof:* Let $3^n+n=2^m$ be a nontrivial solution.
Then with $n=2^kb+a$ for some $b\in\mathbb N_0$ and by the lemma
 $$ 3^n=3^a\cdot (3^{2^k})^b\equiv 3^a\pmod {2^{k+2}}.$$
As $m>n\ge a>k$ we find $3^a+n\equiv 0\pmod{2^{k+2}}$. $_\square$

Using the proprosition we can start with $(k,a)=(3,5)$ and repeatedly replace this with $(k+2, -3^a\bmod {2^{k+2}})$. The process either ends with a pair $(k,a)$ with $a\le k$ (and then necessarily $a=\in\{k,k-1\}$) or it never ends. In the latter case we conclude that no nontrivial solution exists, in the former case we *may* have found a solution, and if we give upprematurely, we at least obtain an estimate and modular condition for all nontrivial solutions. The sequence starts 
$$ (3,5), (5,13), (7,45), (9,173), (11,685), (13,685), (15,25261)$$
and after a few more steps one reaches
$$(k,a)=(201,864075976670532385554180581999784042802808809920656868008621)$$
Especially, $m>n>8.64\cdot 10^{59}$. Also we can continue at leat until $k\approx 8.64\cdot 10^{59}$ and expect $a$ to grow accordinglyet.c sothat the sequence never end and presumably no solution exists.

By taking logarithms, we also find that $\frac{m}{n}$ is an *extremely* good approximation to $\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$, which is also a hint towards non-existence of a solution.